# What can I do with my excess skill points?

Tags: guild-wars-2

I have a level 80 character, and I've already unlocked all of my utility skills. At this point I have over 50 unused skill points, and I'm not sure what I should be doing with them.

[Miyani](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Miyani) sells a variety of items in exchange for skill points, but they're all soulbound/account bound. I understand some are required to create legendary weapons or ascended equipment, but I don't plan on pursuing either of those any time soon so I don't have any need to save my skill points for them.

Is there any effective way to convert my excess skill points into something more useful, like perhaps money?

Comment: I now have over 300 extra skill points on my guardian, with 250 scrolls of knowledge in the bank and all skills unlocked. I've already bought hundreds of siege masters guides and everything I need for a legendary weapon except the precursor. It would be nice if there was even more we could do with skill points.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at the [skill point](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Skill_point) page on the wiki. One of the items you can buy from Miyani is a [Siege Masters (sic) Guide](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Siege_Masters_Guide). Yes, it's soulbound, but you can use it to make things like [Flame Ram Blueprints](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Superior_Flame_Ram_Blueprints), which you can [sell for a tidy sum](http://www.gw2spidy.com/item/21263).

Having said that, the main purpose behind getting more skill points than you need to unlock skills is in fact putting them towards legendary weapons or ascended equipment (where you'll need a *lot* of skill points). I'd at least consider that as a long-term goal (took me about 18 months of only playing occasionally to get Twilight) before just giving up on it and spending all your skill points on money, which can be obtained more easily in other ways.

Comment: You can also buy [Philosopher's Stone](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Philosopher's_Stone) and [Crystals](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Crystal), which can be used to promote crafting materials to the next level - T1 to T2 gives the best [SP to gold ratio](http://ec2-174-129-236-8.compute-1.amazonaws.com:8000/gw2sp2g/).

Comment: @Gwen: Yep, or [Eldritch Scrolls](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Eldritch_Scroll) to make high-end items... and so on. Start at the skill point page I linked to for items Miyani sells for skill points and follow the item links to see what they can be used for.

Answer (score 2):

In the recent update (June 2014?) the Trait organization changed a bit and you may now have top-level traits that you can unlock with Skill points. (You can also unlock them by completing certain events, but for 30 -- I think -- skill points you can unlock one you like but for which you can't really do the event.)